# Consuming onCloseRequest event of tab disables the tab completely

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing an in-app web browser for a JavaFX application which as all browsers, has tabs. The structure of the whole app is based on a `TabPane` in which all of the functionality of the app is shown. When the user selects to use the browser, a new `Tab` (let's call it browserMainTab) is created, and it contains another `TabPane` for the browser tabs. I would like to show a confirmation dialog when the user selects to close the browserMainTab but the inner `TabPane` still has opened tabs. So far, evertyhing is ok, but when I consume the `onCloseRequest` event of browserMainTab the tab stays still active with all its' children but it can't be clicked, dragged, or closed.

```
private void mainBrowserTabCloseConfirmationEvent(Tab tab){

   tab.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
       AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) tab.getContent();
       TabPane browserSubTabPane = (TabPane) pane.getChildren().get(0);

       if(browserSubTabPane.getTabs().size() >= 1){
           StillOpenBrowserTabsAlert alert = new StillOpenBrowserTabsAlert();
           alert.setNumOfOpenTabs(browserSubTabPane.getTabs().size());
           Alert alert1 = alert.alertWithReturnType();

           if(alert1.getResult() == ButtonType.OK){
             getMainTabPane().getTabs().remove(getMainTabPane()
                                               .getSelectionModel()
                                               .getSelectedItem());
           }else{
             event.consume();
           }
       }
    });
 }
```

The above snippet throws no exceptions, and the first part works fine. The issue comes up after I `consume()` the event,  when the tab becomes unclickable. Can somebody help please?

```
         **EDIT**
```

**Reproducible example as requested**

ExampleMain.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExampleMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainTabPane.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

MainTabPane.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainTabPane implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TabPane mainTabPane;
    private SubTabPane subTabPaneController;


    private SubTabPane getSubTabPaneController() {
        return subTabPaneController;
    }

    private void setSubTabPaneController(SubTabPane subTabPaneController) {
        this.subTabPaneController = subTabPaneController;
    }

    private TabPane getMainTabPane() { return mainTabPane; }



    private void loadSubTabPaneAsTabContent(){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("subTabPane.fxml"));
        Parent root = null;
        try{
            root = loader.load();
        }catch (IOException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert root != null;
        setSubTabPaneController(loader.getController());
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab of main TabPane");
        tab.setContent(root);
        getMainTabPane().getTabs().add(tab);
        closeRequestOfMainTabPane(tab);
    }



    private void closeRequestOfMainTabPane(Tab tab){
        tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            int numOfOpenTabsInSubTabPane = getSubTabPaneController().getSubTabPane().getTabs().size();
            if(numOfOpenTabsInSubTabPane >= 1){
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alert.showAndWait();

                if(alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK){
                    getMainTabPane().getTabs().remove(getMainTabPane() 
                                                      .getSelectionModel()
                                                     .getSelectedItem());

                }else{
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Platform.runLater(this::loadSubTabPaneAsTabContent);
        getMainTabPane().setTabDragPolicy(TabPane.TabDragPolicy.REORDER);
    }
}
```

SubTabPane.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class SubTabPane  {
    @FXML private TabPane subTabPane;

    TabPane getSubTabPane() { return subTabPane; }

}
```

mainTabPane.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainTabPane">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="mainTabPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

subTabPane.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SubTabPane">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="subTabPane" layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="593.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre] demonstrating the issue, please?

Comment: It's a quite big application, but I'll try to omit all the rest and explain with words a few parts. Meanwhile, I found a workaround which throws a `ClassCastException` but yields the desired result. I tried catching the exception but it doesn't work. Seems like the Tab is deleted from memory but not graphically. I'll come back soon with a reproducible example.

Comment: Hmm. You have the closing policy set to `UNAVAILABLE`. Is that a mistake or am I misunderstanding the problem? Assuming it was a mistake I set it so the main tab can be closed, yet when I choose "cancel" after the alert is shown nothing appears to break. What version of JavaFX are you using? I tried your code on JavaFX 12.0.2; if you're using an earlier version maybe something was patched?

Comment: That said, swpalmer has a point when he asks, "_Why do you have code to manually remove the tab?_". When the user chooses "ok" then you should simply not consume the event. If the event is not consumed then the `Tab` the `onCloseRequest` handler is being invoked for will close naturally.

Comment: Sorry about the tab policy being set to `UNAVAILABLE`, I forgot to set it correctly during example reproduction.However in the real application it is set as it should. Also the real app does not differ a lot from the example except more classes are involved in order to display the browser. When I select to close the main `Tab` and click cancel, the main Tab stays open but I can't interact with it. Strange, I'm using JavaFX 12.0.1, and Maven 3.6.1

Comment: Yes, swpalmer answer is a correct approach, I'm just trying to leverage the built in tab close policy. The issue appears when the event is consumed. After the event consumption the tab should stay open and wait for another close request but it only stays open and completely disabled. As previously said, I found a workaround by casting the event into an `EventHandler<Event>` and calling it again on the main tab but it throws a `ClassCastException`. Strangely again, it yields the same result. I'll upvote the answeer of swpalmer because it is correct, and others should see it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have code to manually remove the tab?

This works for me:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        CheckBox askFirst = new CheckBox("confirm before allowing close");
        Tab tab = new Tab("Close Me", askFirst);
        tab.setOnCloseRequest((Event t) -> {
            if (askFirst.isSelected()) {
                Alert areYouSureAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
                Optional<ButtonType> result = areYouSureAlert.showAndWait();
                if (result.isEmpty() || result.get() != ButtonType.YES) {
                    t.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        TabPane tp = new TabPane(tab);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tp));
        stage.show();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
    }

}
```

Your problem is in this code:

```
            if(alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK){
                getMainTabPane().getTabs().remove(getMainTabPane() 
                                                  .getSelectionModel()
                                                 .getSelectedItem());

            }else{
                e.consume();
            }
```

all you really need is:

```
    if (alert.getResult() != ButtonType.OK) {
        e.consume();
    }
```

To remove the tab, let the event be pressed, to not close the tab, consume the event.  You are likely confusing the TabPane which thinks it is supposed to be removing a tab that you have already tried to remove.

Comment: Although it is a correct answer and I appreciate it a lot that you answered, it requires me to restructure my scene to find a place for the `CheckBox`. I want to have this exact same result but by using the Tab's build in closing property. Basically, I'm not removing the `Tab` manually I'm trying to replicate the effect of a browser notification when you try to close it with a bunch of tabs open. However, I want this to happen when the Main tab is closed not somekind of window. If I don't find a way to fix the Exception I mentioned before I'll follow your answer and come back to upvote it.

Comment: Also, why did you use this List of integers in the beggining?

Comment: The checkbox is simply a substitute for whatever condition you need to prevent closing of the tab without confirmation.  Replace the if condition with whatever you need.  You mentioned that your main browser tab would contain another TabPane.  Just check that inner TabPane for child tabs, if it still has a (non-empty?) tab then you do the alert.  The integer list was left over from something else. I've removed it.

Comment: Well this is what I'm doing in the reproducible example I provided but when I reach the else condition and consume the event the Main tab stays open and then completely freezes. Slaw said it is working fine in his end though. As I said, I'll dig more into it a bit before following your suggestion just out of curiosity to find the source. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As for the edit you made, I tried this out but nothing, again the tab freezes. The only work around I found so far is to create an `EventHandler<Event>` with a parameter of event and pass it to the `setOnCloseRequest`  and then in the else statement pass the event to another `setOnCloseRequest` on the same tab but this time casted to `EventHandler<Event>`. This throws a `ClassCastException` but gives me the said result.

Comment: nit-pick: implicitExit is true by default :)

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou if there's still a problem after you changed your code to _not_ remove the tab manually, then something else is wrong: rinse and repeat (aka: strip it down to a new [mcve] that demonstrates what/how the outcome is not what you expect :)

Comment: @kleopatra. Well you are right, this is what I'am going to do today. I'll come back in a couple days with the result so the example contains the browser as well in case this is causing the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I tried something similar in an application with tabs coresponding to opened projects. The problem apears when the `TabDragPolicy` is set to `REORDER`, I smash a tab closing button, a confirmirmation dialog apears asking me if I'd like to save the project, and the event gets consumed if I cancel tab closing. If you remove any of these three (the drag policy, the dialog or event consuming), the tab does not freeze. Removing tab and adding it back to the same position helps, but looks ugly.

The following approach works perfectly for some reason:

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            tab.getTabPane().setTabDragPolicy(TabPane.TabDragPolicy.FIXED);

            // your confirmation code

            Platform.runLater(() -> tab.getTabPane().setTabDragPolicy(TabPane.TabDragPolicy.REORDER));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the bug in the end. This was happening because I had a `TabDragPolicy` enabled during initialization. I never thought that this could cause such problem so this is why I didn't mention it. It seems that when I `consume()` the event, the `TabDragPolicy` is not applied anymore and this makes the `Tab` to completely freeze. Once I removed the `TabDragPolicy.REORDER` from `initialize` the issue stopped.